# Math.Random - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've this code:

```
            var num = 550;
            $(document).keydown(function (event) {
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    // Left Arrow                
                    case 37: num = num-- - 15;
                        document.getElementById('player').style.margin = '550px ' + num + 'px 0px ';
                        break;
                    // Right Arrow                
                    case 39: num = 15 + num++;
                        document.getElementById('player').style.margin = '550px ' + num + 'px 0px ';
                        break;
                }
            });
            var nump = 0;
            var touch = false;
            var flagtouch;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                flagtouch = setInterval(function () {
                    movePoint(nump);

                }, 10);
            });
            function movePoint() {
                document.getElementById('point').style.margin = nump + 'px 615px 0px';
                touch = chekTouch($('#point'), $('#player'))   // check whether the divs touches and return true if touched
                if (touch) {
                    $('.point').ready(function () {
                        var docWidth = $(document).width();
                        var $div = $('.point');
                        var divWidth = $div.width();
                        var widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
                        $div.css({
                            marginLeft: Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax),
                            marginTop: 150,
                        });
                    });
                }
                else {
                    nump++;
                }
            }

            function chekTouch($div1, $div2) {
                var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
                var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
                var h1 = $div1.outerHeight();
                var w1 = $div1.outerWidth();
                var b1 = y1 + h1;
                var r1 = x1 + w1;
                var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
                var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
                var h2 = $div2.outerHeight();
                var w2 = $div2.outerWidth();
                var b2 = y2 + h2;
                var r2 = x2 + w2;

                if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
                return true;
            }
```

Now, I got this touch function, when div **point** touches div **player** he excute marginLeft in random way and marginTop to 0px.

So its working but only 1 issue, the random isn't stop working, he keep move when the div has physicall contact each other.

My question is how can I make the random margin work only when he touch the div?

Thanks!

Comment: How does it helps me?

Comment: At least for me your code is much too large to work it through. Isolate the real problem and just post the *relevant* parts of your code. This increases the chances, that anybody here will help you.

Comment: From a quick look: remove the `$('.point').ready(function () {` part in `movePoint()` --> just execute the code immediately.

Comment: It containing jQuery inside..

Comment: @Sirko alright i'll edit my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// - it is because you are using setInterval which plays forever every 10ms

**Edit:**

Sorry I misunderstood what you meant,

after it touches you should clear the interval like this :

```
clearInterval(flagtouch);
```

then the loop will stop

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iqedop/1/edit)**

Comment: Then what should i use, got any solution for me? EDIT: You should try the code, he working fine.. I think you wrong..

Comment: But you still didn't gave me a solution, what should i use?

Comment: Sorry, now I think I did :)

Comment: Can you perhaps help me moving it down? should i add return true?

Comment: Can you fiddle it for me? it just doesn't working fine since i added clearInterval.

Comment: here you go http://jsbin.com/araten/1/edit but I think you could implement this game in a better way using position absolute ..

Answer (score 1):

In `movePoint()`, after you set the randomly set the margin when `touch` was *true*, you **still** set the margin with `document.getElementById('point').style.margin = nump + 'px 615px 0px';` at every interval, but don't increase `nump`, so `touch` will **always** be *true* after that.